# Is there any function in TensorFlow equivalent to python reduce?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want a function in TensorFlow which has the same effect as Pythion `reduce()`

For example, if I have a tensor `a` with value `[a1, a2, a3]` and a function `func()`, I want `[func(a1, a2), func(func(a1, a2), a3)]`. If `a` is a Python list I can simply do

```py
from functools import reduce
# a = [a1, a2, a3]
A = reduce(func, a)
```

What if `a` is a Tensor (not a python list!) of TF object and I want the same A? If no alternative TF function, how can I do it effectively?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually mean reduce, so the tensorflow equivalent are [tf.foldl](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/foldl) and [tf.foldr](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/foldr).
Example:

```
elems = tf.constant(["hello", "my", "name", "is", "inigo", "montoya"])
tf.foldl(lambda a, x: a +" " + x, elems)
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'hello my name is inigo montoya'>
tf.foldr(lambda a, x: a +" " + x, elems)
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'montoya inigo is name my hello'>
```

However, according to your example you probably want [tf.scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan):

```
tf.scan(lambda a, x: a +" " + x, elems)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=string, numpy=
    ([b'hello', b'hello my', b'hello my name', b'hello my name is',
    b'hello my name is inigo', b'hello my name is inigo montoya'], dtype=object)>
```

Comment: This is the real solution and not the `py_function` one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned which type of `func` you would like to achieve, i.e whether you just wanted to simply add all tensors, or take mean etc. For those type of operations there is [tf.reduce_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum), and set of other reduce operations. But if you want to have your own custom operation to be implemented by means of reduce, you can achieve it with [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/py_function). Check the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import reduce

tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.random.normal([1, 4]))
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.random.normal([1, 4]))
z = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.random.normal([1, 4]))

print('X = ', x.numpy())
print('Y = ', y.numpy())
print('Z = ', z.numpy())

def custom_function(*elements):
    data = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, elements)
    return data


result = tf.py_function(custom_function, [x, y, z], Tout=tf.float32)
print('Result = ', result.numpy())
```

Output:

```
X =  [[ 0.9403639  -0.41230875  0.08281742  0.24365784]]
Y =  [[-1.2166423  -0.18330204 -1.2322044  -1.1254508 ]]
Z =  [[-0.42474216  0.997245   -2.319666    1.4623599 ]]
Result =  [[-0.70102054  0.40163422 -3.4690528   0.5805669 ]]
```

**EDIT:**

The output of any `reduce` function in Python has to be a single value. In your case, you wish to accumulate the values of subsequent elements in a tensor and in the end produce another 1 dimensional Tensor.

I can't think of any built-in TensorFlow equivalent operation which can be used in this way. But, we can do the processing by indexing of tensor elements. However, I am not sure, how much this solution can integrate with your overall model architecture. Check the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.random.normal([5]))
print('X = ', x.numpy())

y = []
sum = x[0]
for index in range(1, len(x)):
    sum += x[index]
    y.append(sum)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
print('Sum = ', y.numpy())
```

Output:

```
X =  [ 1.0281714  -1.5870513  -1.7896062   0.11207424  0.50049555]
Sum =  [-0.55887985 -2.348486   -2.2364118  -1.7359163 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited my problem to express it more clearly. In your reply, `[x, y, z]` is still a Python list, however, my input is a TF 1D-Tensor and could not be applied to `reduce` function directly. BTW,  tf.reduce_sum cannot help, because I want `[sum(a1, a2), sum(sum(a1,a2), a3)]` instead of `sum(a1,a2,a3)`

Comment: Edited the solution as per your requirements. Hope it is helpful to you.